How to change a single cell in a data range Google Sheets Script
As noted in the code below I can do my loop and read data from the cells but I don't know how to modify a single cell.
function modifyDataInRange(){
  var range1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MyData').getRange("A2:J300");
  var checkData = range1.getValues();
  var j = 0;
  while(checkData[j][0]!=""){
    if(checkData[j][1] == "Old Data"){
      checkData[j][1] = "New Data";         //this does not write to the cell
      range1.setValue("New Data");          //this writes to every cell in the range
    }
    j += 1;
  }
}

Is there a way to do something like range1.setvalue([j][1], "New Data")?
[Update]
Based on Cooper's reply I created another variable as a sheet, now I have a sheet, a range, and data and I'm able to run the following...  Not sure that I will need the range variable though.
function modifyDataInRange(){
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MyData');
  var range1 = sheet1.getRange("A2:J300");
  var checkData = range1.getValues();
  var j = 0;
  while(checkData[j][0]!=""){
    if(checkData[j][1] == "Old Data"){
      sheet1.getRange(j+2,1).setValue("New Data")
    }
    j += 1;
  }
}


sheet.getRange(row,column)..setValue(new value);

Based on that reply I created another variable as a sheet, now I have a sheet, a range, and data and I'm able to run the following.
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MyData');
  var range1 = sheet1.getRange("A2:J300");
  var checkData = range1.getValues();
  var j = 0;
  while(checkData[j][0]!=""){
    if(checkData[j][1] == "Old Data"){
      sheet1.getRange(j,1).setValue("New Data")
    }
    j += 1;
  }
}```

You'd get an error that the starting range is too small with that modified code. Try changing it to sheet1.getRange(j+2,1) since your script's supposed to start from the 2nd row.

Thanks for pointing that out, I'm sure I would have caught it eventually... :)

You can also do it this way:
function modifyDataInRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rg = sh.getRange("A2:J12");
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  let o = vs.map(([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]) => (b == "Old Data") ? [a,"New Data",c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j] : [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]);
  rg.setValues(o);
}


I'm fairly new to scripts and not familiar for the last part of your code.  Is there documentation for it or can you give further information for what this is doing?

It's just a map with an if else in the return.  If col2 is "Old Data" then it return the row with col2 being New Data otherwise it just returns the same row.  And the parameter are using an array literal assignment into each element of the array.
